# Can I force a dhcp server to re-evaluate leases?

Tags: linux, networking, dhcp

I am building servers in VMWare VCenters with packer.   During the dev process, I am building and tearing down servers frequently, (although one-at-a-time) and I'm at the stage where new servers aren't getting an IP address.   It's just occurred to me that this may be because the server isn't aware that clients are dead; the lease is given for a certain period, and can't be rescinded.  Eventually, all available addresses are leased - mostly by ghost servers - so I don't get an address.

So is there a way of (from the network - I don't have access to the server) asking the server to confirm all it's leased addresses?   I'd imagine not, since that might cause all sorts of issues - but any suggestions would be gratefully received.

I'm going to reduce the lease time while testing for future builds.

I don't believe that this is a duplicate; I have searched for similar questions and haven't found what I need.
The client is Linux - I'm not sure what the server is running - it there a "what are you" request I can send?

Comment: Interesting idea - I could get the server to send it's mac address somewhere.  Hmmm.  How does that machine release the ghosts - and presumably it has to be on the dhcp network itself?

Comment: Talk to your colleague managing the DHCP server. He can help you out. He wont bite, I promise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not aware of any DHCP server the will check to see if an ip address that was previously issued is still alive.  Your only option is to reduce the lease time so your address space can be reclaimed.  I would also recommend that you increase your address size so you don't risk running out of addresses.

Furthermore, without access to the DHCP server, your options are limited.  No sure of your setup, but you might be able to put a NAT router between the DHCP server and the test network you are working with.  That way you would only need one IP address from the other network.

Comment: Thanks @Joe - sadly I'm not able to change the address space, nor to implement a NAT router.   I'm thinking of having a shutdown command release the lease.  Not really thought that through yet , but I will be turning the server into a template, so it doesn't need the lease, and as long as I remove the "release the lease" code as soon as it's run, I think I should be good.